# References a ideas behind weight functions

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have some questions about weight functions:

- if we consider the $L^2$ norm with a weight of a function $f$:
  $$\int_\mathbb{R} w(x)|f(x)|^2 dx,$$
  what is the idea of considering the weight function?
- Which properties these objects have?
- Do you have some recommendation about references for learning weight functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing, by using a weight function, is to consider $L^2$ with respect to a different measure. Roughly, if you define
$$
\mu(E)=\int_{\mathbb R} 1_E(x)\,w(x)\,dx,
$$
then
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|^2\,w(x)\,dx=\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|^2\,d\mu. 
$$
Keywords are *absolute continuity* and *Radon Nikodym Derivative*.

Comment: Another keyword is probability mass/density function